# ingress with minikube working differently on Mac vs Ubuntu. When to set etc/hosts to 127.0.0.1 vs "minikube ip"?

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I have a simple ingress file that does work on multiple environments, but to access it, it behaves differently depending on if I'm running my minikube cluster on my Mac or my Ubuntu machines.

Specifically, for my mac, I have to add the the entry:
`127.0.0.1   my.kube` to /etc/hosts, and also run `minikube tunnel`
for me to be able to access my application in the browser at `http://my.kube`.

But, for my Ubuntu system, I have to get the `minikube ip` and place the resulting ip in `/etc/hosts` like `192.168.49.2   my.kube` for example. And then I do NOT need to run `minikube tunnel`.

While I can see the pros and cons of each:

1. using a `127.0.0.1` and a tunnel removes a dependency on the minikube ip, which could change if the cluster is deleted and recreated (although some work has gone on to make it persistent).
2. using the minikube ip and not needing a tunnel is nice too.

But, my question is why are things behaving differently at all?

I have enabled the ingress addon on both environments with `minikube addons enable ingress`.

When I check the hostname of the loadBalancer created by the ingress with `kubectl get ingress my-ingress -o yaml` I get the same result for both. I expected to see an IP in the case where the minikube IP is used (Ubuntu).

```
....
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: localhost
```

Again, all services are up and running fine, it's just a question of what goes in `/etc/hosts` and whether `minikube tunnel` is or is not running.

Also, to be clear, my Ubuntu system will not work with `127.0.0.1` and `minikube tunnel`. I can't find a common approach for the two environments.

For reference, here is my ingress file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my.kube
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-ui
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /api
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-api
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Some names have been changed to protect the innocent.

Just for completeness, the services are just simply:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-ui
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-ui
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-api
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-api
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

Comment: Please provide more information like the driver used in each minikube installation, are you using NGINX controller as described here:https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/ ? Post the complete implementation manifests including service and deployment (without any sensitive information). Are you aware that when running the minikube tunnel command you should do it in a separate window to keep it running?.

Comment: I am using the default ingress controller which is NGINX.
Yes, the tunnel is run in a separate window.
Services and deployments are working.

Comment: And the driver? Are you using the same driver in both minikube installations? If so, which one? https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/

Comment: It's the Docker driver. I just checked my Mac. On my Ubuntu I used the default which is also Docker, but will have to wait to check to verify this evening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minikube supports ingress differently on the Mac and Linux.

On Linux the ingress is fully supported and therefore does not need the use of `minikube tunnel`.

On Mac there is an open issue due to a network issue. The documentation states that the minikube ingress addon is not supported, but I argue that that is highly misleading if not incorrect. It's just supported differently (and not as well).

On both Mac and Linux `minikube addons enable ingress` is required. Enabling the ingress addon on Mac shows that the ingress will be available on 127.0.0.1 as shown in the screenshot, whereas Linux will make it available by the `minikube ip`. Then, when we start `minikube tunnel` on the Mac it will connect to the ingress like any other exposed service.

[image: minikube commands in CLI]

Thanks to Gabriel for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are describing is most probably because the `ingress` and `ingress-dns` addons are currently only supported on Linux Systems when using the Docker driver, as mentioned in the [Known Issues](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/#known-issues) section of the minikube documentation.

Comment: Big thanks. That got me going in the right direction.