# Unable to reach the application using Ingress in Minikube (macOS)

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress

I am trying to follow this tutorial to setup Minikube on my MacBook.

[Minikube with ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/)

I have also referred [Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561682/minikube-with-ingress-example-not-working) and [Stack over flow question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70961901/ingress-with-minikube-working-differently-on-mac-vs-ubuntu-when-to-set-etc-host) both of these are not working for me.

When I run `Minikube tunnel` it says to enter the password and then get stuck after entering my password.

```
sidharth@Sidharths-MacBook-Air helm % minikube tunnel     
✅  Tunnel successfully started
 
  NOTE: Please do not close this terminal as this process must stay alive for the     tunnel to be accessible ...

❗  The service/ingress example-ingress requires privileged ports to be exposed: [80 443]
  sudo permission will be asked for it.
❗  The service/ingress minimal-ingress requires privileged ports to be exposed [80 443]
  Starting tunnel for service example-ingress.
  sudo permission will be asked for it.
  Starting tunnel for service minimal-ingress.
Password:
```

I am getting the below response when I run `kubectl ge ingress`

```
NAME              CLASS   HOSTS              ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
example-ingress   nginx   hello-world.info   localhost   80      34m
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue specifically with the docker driver, and it's only an output issue. If you use a VM driver (like hyperkit for macOS), you'll get the expected output in the documentation.

This stems from the fact that we need to do two discrete things to tunnel for a container driver (since it needs to route to 127.0.0.1) and for a VM driver.

We can potentially look into fixing this so that the output for both versions are similar, but the tunnel itself is working fine.

Refer this [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/12899) link for more information.

Comment: Well I am using an M1 chip and it does not  support virtulization. This means I could never using ingress on Minikube ?

Comment: Can you try mapping. For minikube tunnel to work is to map "127.0.0.1" in /etc/hosts, instead of the output from minikube IP or the ingress description.

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac's with M1 chips, I can use minikube with podman (can brew install both).  The "minikube tunnel" will ask for password and then appear to hang, because it's essentially establishing a tunnel similar to "kubectl port-forward" with that process between 127.0.0.1:443 and your ingress, and that tunnel will disappear once you ctrl-c out of the "minikube tunnel" process.

Note, this is different from the experience/behavior you'll get if you're using minikube with virtualbox on an Intel-based Mac, which will return the list of mapped ports and always has the ingress reachable from on the virtualbox VM.