# Minikube ingress hangs when connecting

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress

I have added the ingress with `minikube addons enable ingress` and have verified that it is running:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create-pzhzn        0/1     Completed   0          53m
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-k9xdn         0/1     Completed   0          53m
ingress-nginx-controller-7c6974c4d8-rkcrp   1/1     Running     0          53m
```

I then get the minikube ip:

```
$ minikube ip
192.168.49.2
```

And here is my deployment/service/ingress definition:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: karpenter-test-deployment
  labels:
    app: karpenter-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: karpenter-test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: karpenter-test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: karpenter-test-manager
        image: localhost/test-karpenter-manager:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: karpenter-test-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: karpenter-test
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: karpenter-test-service
            port:
              number: 8000
```

I can verify that it is running because it shows up in pods:

```
$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
karpenter-test-deployment-945ff8f95-fbv24   1/1     Running   0          95m   10.244.0.3   minikube   <none>           <none>
```

But when I try to go to `http://192.168.49.2/api` in a browser, it just hangs indefinitely. To be totally sure, I exposed the service directly:

```
$ kubectl port-forward service/karpenter-test-service 8000:8000
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8000 -> 8000
Forwarding from [::1]:8000 -> 8000
Handling connection for 8000
```

And then I was able to access the service at `http://localhost:8000/api`.

Why does it always just hang when I try to access the ingress directly?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe is probably because the `ingress` and `ingress-dns` add-ons are currently only [supported](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/#known-issues) [due to some complexities](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/addons/ingress-dns/) on Linux Systems (not MacOS) when using the Docker driver, as mentioned in the Known Issues section of the minikube documentation.

You can also try to use [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75214415/12818462) to expose a service on MacOS.

Comment: I'm using the podman driver on Linux, I'll have a look at those links, thanks

Comment: Podman is the experimental driver. Anyway, there are no issues related to ingress declared by docs; however, there is an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/14932 that says it can be related to the rootless nature of the Podman.